# Get like_count & comments_count for Instagram Media object with Facebook Instagram API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to build a simple widget that helps users to get their Instagram feed on their websites. I have already got my FB app approved for instagram_graph_user_profile and instagram_graph_user_media permissions.

Now, whenever I try to get the number of likes/comments through the below API call, I get data for all the fields, except like_count and comments_count.

```
https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,media_type,media_url,username,comments_count,like_count,timestamp,permalink,comments_count,caption,children,thumbnail_url&access_token={access_token}
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing something. So, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You appear to be mixing things up here between the Instagram Graph API, and the Instagram Basic Display API. `graph.instagram.com` accesses the latter, but likes & comments count are only available via the former (and thereby only for business / creator accounts, that have been connected to a Facebook page.)

Comment: @CBroe Gotcha, but may I ask does that mean I will not be able to show the number of comments/likes for regular (not business / creator ) Instagram account ?

Comment: Yes it does, because https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/media#fields lists all the fields you can get for media objects get via the IG Basic Display API, and those counts aren’t among them.

Comment: @CBroe Well, now I'm trying to put things up together. I've checked https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/media#get-media

Now, I'm trying to call the API below, but I'm getting 
error message "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '17841404313229702' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions"

graph.facebook.com/{instagram-id}/media?fields=id&access_token={access_token}

Comment: @Abanob Akram You need these permissions: pages_show_list, instagram_basic,
instagram_manage_insights, public_profile, when getting your token via Facebook login. Then from me/accounts, find the id of ur connected page, then find the id of ur instagram business account, then you can call media, and then you can ask for likes and comments on the id of that media

Answer (score 1):

For those looking to integrate it to **business / creator** accounts. You may want to look at this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/) for the supported fields. Also be sure to check the required permissions.

Sample HTTP Get: [https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/{media_id}?fields=id,caption,media_type,like_count,comments_count,media_url&access_token={access_token}](https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/%7Bmedia_id%7D?fields=id,caption,media_type,like_count,comments_count,media_url&access_token=%7Baccess_token%7D)

Comment: Somehow that is not working for me (https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields='+ fields +'&access_token='+ token +'&limit='+ limit) jquery code i putted the comments_count and like_count in the fields variable. the dump gives nothing back.. do you have any idea what im doing wrong?